# Display image in a PIL format from torch.Tensor

Tags: pytorch

I’m quite new to Pytorch. I was wondering how I could convert my tensor of size `torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])` to display in an image format on a Jupyter notebook. A PIL format or a CV2 format should be fine.

I tried using `transforms.ToPILImage(x)` but it resulted in a different format like this: `ToPILImage(mode=ToPILImage(mode=tensor([[[[1.3034e-16, 1.3034e-16, 1.3034e-16, ..., 1.4475e-16,.`

Maybe I’m doing something wrong :no_mouth:

Comment: The image may be normalized. You will have to unnormalize it first.

Comment: Yes, it is. How do I denormalize it? Should I just multiply it by 255? @akshayk07

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your image is normalized, you need to unnormalize it. You have to do the reverse operations that you did during normalization. One way is

```
class UnNormalize(object):
    def __init__(self, mean, std):
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std

    def __call__(self, tensor):
        """
        Args:
            tensor (Tensor): Tensor image of size (C, H, W) to be normalized.
        Returns:
            Tensor: Normalized image.
        """
        for t, m, s in zip(tensor, self.mean, self.std):
            t.mul_(s).add_(m)
            # The normalize code -> t.sub_(m).div_(s)
        return tensor
```

To use this, you'll need the mean and standard deviation (which you used to normalize the image). Then,

```
unorm = UnNormalize(mean = [0.35675976, 0.37380189, 0.3764753], std = [0.32064945, 0.32098866, 0.32325324])
image = unorm(normalized_image)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @akshay07